# Connection timeout issue while generating PDF using TCPDF

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

If we remove `<td>`from below code it generate PDF(using TCPDF) else it gives error as `Connection Timeout`.

```
$curImageSrc = is_file("$image_dir/".$img['filename']) == true ? image_tag("../$image_dir/".$img['filename'], array('size'=>'200x150','align'=>'center','alt'=>$img['caption'])) : '';
        print <<<EOT
          <td width=25% $tdvalue_css>
            <div align="center">
              $curImageSrc
              <br />
              <u style="font-weight:bold">{$img['image_caption']}</u>
            </div>&nbsp;
          </td>

    EOT;
```

Please guide me, how we can resolve this issue? I tried using div-table structure but not working, table structure get disturbed in PDF output.

Comment: I am not sure your code has a correct syntax. When using HEREDOC sytax for string, the closing tag must be alone on its line without blank characters at the beginning of the line. You should turn `____EOT;` to `EOT;` (without spaces) http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Actual code is without space, while copy-pasting code... space got added.

Comment: Could you improve a bit the question with regard to: What is the function that generate the PDF. Is it `image_tag()`? Is `$tdvalue_css` defined somewhere (used in EOT)? Have you any error in the `php_error.log` file?

Comment: @mat I have not pasted full code. yes,`$tdvalue_css` is defined.   `image_tag()` is symfony function to generated ` <img...>` tag.  Above code snippet is where  I found issue while debugging.